# Can a QueryString parameter be bound to a complex object if the complex object has implicit casting from string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**Short Question:**

Provided I have given an implicit conversion mechanism for my object to convert its values from a plain string, can it be made to auto-bind to ViewModel's property?

**Details:**

I have a complex object like so (simplified for brevity and clarity)

```
public enum PrimaryScopeEnum {
    Pivot1,
    Pivot2
}

public enum SecondaryScopeEnum {
    Entity1,
    Entity2,
    Entity3,
    Entity4
}

public class DataScope {
    public PrimaryScopeEnum PrimaryScope { get; set; }
    public SecondaryScopeEnum SecondaryScope { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator DataScope ( string combinedScope ) {
        DataScope ds = new DataScope();
        // Logic for populating Primary and Secondary Scope enums
        return ds;
    }
}
```

I am using the above object in my view model as below:

```
public enum PageModeEnum {
    View,
    Add,
    Edit
}

public class DisplayInfoViewModel {
    public string SetID { get; set; }
    public PageModeEnum PageMode { get; set; } 
    public DataScope Scope { get; set; }
}
```

And the Action in my Controller is set as

```
// Accessed with /MyController/DisplayInfo?SetID=22&PageMode=View&Scope=Pivot1
public virtual ActionResult DisplayInfo ( DisplayInfoViewModel vm ) {
    // vm.SetID is 22
    // vm.PageMode is PageModeEnum.View
    // vm.Scope is null
    return View ( vm );
}
```

My issue is in the Action, even though I have given an implicit casting from string to `DataScope` class it fails to properly bind during execution.

I have tested the casting with the value that is being passed (Pivot1 here) separately and the casting works fine.

Is there a way to make this casting happen implicitly or should I change the view models `Scope` variable to plain string and then do a manual casting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the default model binder doesn't use any implicit operators. You will have to write a custom model binder for the `DataScope` type and manually bind it from the request string if you want that to work.

For example:

```
public class DataScopeModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return (DataScope)value.RawValue;
    }
}
```

which you are then going to associate with the `DataScope` type in your `Application_Start`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DataScope), new DataScopeModelBinder());
```

Comment: I wouldn't use any enums or implicit operators on my view models.

Comment: Ok, I can understand the reason you are not recommending using Enums and complex objects. Thank you.